# ¿Cómo cambiar el estilo CSS de un elemento en particular?

Tags: html, html5, css, css3

Tengo una página web HTML con varios elementos, pero la finalidad es solicitar el usuario y password. Lo que estoy intentando realizar es que cuando el usuario tenga el cursor en el elemento input email, mediante css le aparezca el mensaje contenido en el elemento b: **"Por favor teclee su correo electrónico o usuario"**, y cuando el usuario tenga el cursor en el elemento input password, mediante css le aparezca el mensaje contenido en el elemento b: **"Teclee su contraseña"**.
**No tengo permitido usar jQuery.**

Muchas gracias de antemano y saludos

Mi código es el siguiente:

CSS:

```
input.dx-texteditor-input:focus + .tooltip
{
  opacity: 1;
}  

input.dx-texteditor-input: focus + .tooltip-top-right
{
  right: 0; 
  left: auto; 
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<label class="input">
    <i class="icon-append fa fa-lock" style="z-index: 1"></i>
    <div class="dx-texteditor dx-texteditor-empty dx-show-clear-button dx-widget dx-textbox">
        <div class="dx-texteditor-container">
            <input class="dx-texteditor-input" name="email" type="email">
            <div class="dx-placeholder"></div>
            <div class="dx-texteditor-buttons-container">
                <span class="dx-clear-button-area" onclick="void(0)">
                    <span class="dx-icon dx-icon-clear"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <b class="tooltip tooltip-top-right" style="opacity:0">
        <i class="fa fa-user txt-color-teal"></i> Por favor teclee su correo electrónico o usuario
    </b>
</label>  

<label class="input">
    <i class="icon-append fa fa-lock" style="z-index: 1"></i>
    <div class="dx-texteditor dx-texteditor-empty dx-show-clear-button dx-widget dx-textbox">
        <div class="dx-texteditor-container">
            <input class="dx-texteditor-input" name="email" type="email">
            <div class="dx-placeholder"></div>
            <div class="dx-texteditor-buttons-container">
                <span class="dx-clear-button-area" onclick="void(0)">
                    <span class="dx-icon dx-icon-clear"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <b class="tooltip tooltip-top-right" style="opacity:0">
        <i class="fa fa-lock txt-color-teal"></i> Teclee su contraseña
    </b>
</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar el selector `~` de CSS combinado con `:focus`

`~` es para seleccionar un elemento posterior en el DOM y `:focus` para seleccionarlo cuando el `<input>` tenga el foco. Lo importante de este selector (`~`) es que el elemento que modificas tiene que estar después del elemento que dispara la acción (después en el DOM).

Como la propiedad `content` solo funciona con pseudo elementos, estoy agregando `:after` para poder mostrar el mensaje.

Salu2

```css
#identidad:focus ~ #tip:after {
  content: "Escriba su nombre de usuario o direccion de correo electronico";
}

#password:focus ~ #tip:after {
  content: "Escriba su contraseña";
}
```

```html
<input id="identidad">
<input id="password">
<p id="tip"></p>
```

<sub>nota: Los demás estilos de formato los elimine por legibilidad.</sub>

Si quieres dos lugares separados y poner el contenido en el DOM directamente, solo cambian los ids y puedes usar `visibility` o `opacity` la cual puedes combinar con transiciones para darle un poco de animación.

```css
#tipPass, #tipId {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#identidad:focus ~ #tipId,
#password:focus ~ #tipPass {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<input id="identidad">
<p id="tipId">Escriba su nombre de usuario o direccion de correo electronico</p>
<input id="password">
<p id="tipPass">Escriba su contraseña</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Crear **Tooltips** con estilos css [Documentación](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp).

**Ejemplo** práctico solo con estilos **css**:

```css
[data-tip] {
  position:relative;
}

[data-tip]:before {
  content:'';
  display:none;
  content:'';
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #1a1a1a; 
  position:absolute;
  top:30px;
  left:35px;
  z-index:8;
  font-size:0;
  line-height:0;
  width:0;
  height:0;
}

[data-tip]:after {
  display:none;
  content:attr(data-tip);
  position:absolute;
  top:35px;
  left:0px;
  padding:5px 8px;
  background:#1a1a1a;
  color:#fff;
  z-index:9;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  height:18px;
  line-height:18px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  white-space:nowrap;
  word-wrap:normal;
}

[data-tip]:hover:before,
[data-tip]:hover:after {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div data-tip="Por favor teclee su correo electrónico o usuario">
<input type="email" name="email">
</div>
```

> **Nota:** No necesariamente tiene que ser una etiqueta `div` puedes remplazar por una etiqueta `<label>`.

Puedes prácticar los estilos **css** en la consola del navegador (**herramientas para desarrolladores**) y darles otra funcionalidad según lo requieras.

Otro **ejemplo:**

```css
.tooltip {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
visibility: hidden;
width: 120px;
background-color: black;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 6px;
padding: 5px 0;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
top: -5px;
left: 110%;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
right: 100%;
margin-top: -5px;
border-width: 5px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: transparent black transparent transparent;
}
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Comprueba si te valdría con la solución que dan en este otro hilo.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480010/adding-a-tooltip-to-an-input-box

Te dejo aqui el link directo: http://jsfiddle.net/BumU5/3/

Answer (score 0):

Esta es una solución rápida, puedes mejorar la función con parentNode y closest, para hacerla mas universal.

JAVASCRIPT

```
function showTooltip(id){
  document.querySelector(id).style.opacity = 1;
}
function hideTooltip(id){
  document.querySelector(id).style.opacity = 0;
}
```

CSS

```
.tooltip{
  opacity:0;
}
input.dx-texteditor-input:focus + .tooltip
{
  opacity: 1;
}  

input.dx-texteditor-input: focus + .tooltip-top-right
{
  right: 0; 
  left: auto; 
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

HTML

```
    <label class="input">
    <i class="icon-append fa fa-lock" style="z-index: 1"></i>
    <div class="dx-texteditor dx-texteditor-empty dx-show-clear-button dx-widget dx-textbox">
        <div class="dx-texteditor-container">
            <input onblur="hideTooltip('#tooltip1')" onfocus="showTooltip('#tooltip1')" class="dx-texteditor-input" name="email" type="email">
            <div class="dx-placeholder"></div>
            <div class="dx-texteditor-buttons-container">
                <span class="dx-clear-button-area" onclick="void(0)">
                    <span class="dx-icon dx-icon-clear"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <b id="tooltip1" class="tooltip tooltip-top-right" >
        <i class="fa fa-user txt-color-teal"></i> Por favor teclee su correo electrónico o usuario
    </b>
</label>  

<label class="input">
    <i class="icon-append fa fa-lock" style="z-index: 1"></i>
    <div class="dx-texteditor dx-texteditor-empty dx-show-clear-button dx-widget dx-textbox">
        <div class="dx-texteditor-container">
            <input onblur="hideTooltip('#tooltip2')" onfocus="showTooltip('#tooltip2')" class="dx-texteditor-input" name="email" type="email">
            <div class="dx-placeholder"></div>
            <div class="dx-texteditor-buttons-container">
                <span class="dx-clear-button-area" onclick="void(0)">
                    <span class="dx-icon dx-icon-clear"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <b id="tooltip2" class="tooltip tooltip-top-right">
        <i class="fa fa-lock txt-color-teal"></i> Teclee su contraseña
    </b>
```

Existe una forma de hacerlo con puro css pero aún no es un standard y sería algo así, solo es la idea, no lo he probado

```
!.input > input:focus  .tooltip{ opacity:1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Un par de cosas:

- Para que funcione tu código necesitas que el elemento `b` esté
  justo después del `input` (es lo que significa el selector de hermanos
  adyacentes: `elemento1 + elemento`2) se aplica al `elemento2` que va
  inmediatamente después del `elemento1`.
- La segunda cosa es que al
  tener definida la opacidad en el HTML necesitas poner un `!important`
  en tu CSS para que sobreescriba la propiedad.

```css
input.dx-texteditor-input:focus + .tooltip {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

input.dx-texteditor-input:focus + .tooltip-top-right {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<label class="input">
  <i class="icon-append fa fa-lock" style="z-index: 1"></i>
  <div class="dx-texteditor dx-texteditor-empty dx-show-clear-button dx-widget dx-textbox">
    <div class="dx-texteditor-container">
      <input class="dx-texteditor-input" name="email" type="email">
      <b class="tooltip tooltip-top-right" style="opacity:0">
        <i class="fa fa-user txt-color-teal"></i> Por favor teclee su correo electrónico o usuario
    </b>
      <div class="dx-placeholder"></div>
      <div class="dx-texteditor-buttons-container">
        <span class="dx-clear-button-area" onclick="void(0)">
                    <span class="dx-icon dx-icon-clear"></span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</label>

<label class="input">
  <i class="icon-append fa fa-lock" style="z-index: 1"></i>
  <div class="dx-texteditor dx-texteditor-empty dx-show-clear-button dx-widget dx-textbox">
    <div class="dx-texteditor-container">
      <input class="dx-texteditor-input" name="email" type="email">
      <b class="tooltip tooltip-top-right" style="opacity:0">
        <i class="fa fa-lock txt-color-teal"></i> Teclee su contraseña
    </b>
      <div class="dx-placeholder"></div>
      <div class="dx-texteditor-buttons-container">
        <span class="dx-clear-button-area" onclick="void(0)">
                    <span class="dx-icon dx-icon-clear"></span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</label>
```